# TSQL, how to retrieve data from multiple JSON rows from a database

Tags: sql, json, t-sql

I have in my table rows with JSON same as a example:

| json_data |
| --- |
| [{"d":"2021-05-05T12:16:18.9175335","l":"temp12@cor.net","a":"test1","c":"Kom1"}] |
| [{"d":"2021-05-05T12:16:37.7258608","l":"temp12@cor.net","a":"test2","c":"Kom2"}] |
| [{"d":"2021-05-05T12:17:30.2390585","l":"temp12@cor.net","a":"test3","c":"Kom3"}] |

I want to get data in table format. When is 1 row i don't have problem using:

```
DECLARE @JSONINPUT NVARCHAR(max)  
SET @JSONINPUT = (select top 1 cast(json_data as varchar(max)) from mytable )

IF (ISJSON(@JSONINPUT) = 1)  
BEGIN  
SELECT * from OPENJSON(@JSONINPUT )
WITH (
[Kom] nvarchar(max) '$.c',
[Date] DATETIME2  '$.d',
[User] nvarchar(150) '$.a'
);
END
```

and i get:

| Com | Date | User |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Kom1 | 2021-05-05 12:16:18.9175335 | test1 |

But I don't know how to get data from all rows.

Comment: The syntax is identical, apart from reference the column not your scalar variable. I.e. INstead of `OPENJSON(@JSONINPUT )` it would be `OPENJSON(YT.JsonColumn)`; where `YT` is the alias of YourTable (reference earlier in the `FROM`) and `JsonColumn` is, unsurprisingly, the column with the JSON in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CROSS APPLY` with `OPENJSON`

```
SELECT j.Kom, j.[Date], j.[User]
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(json_data)
WITH (
    [Kom] nvarchar(max) '$.c',
    [Date] DATETIME2  '$.d',
    [User] nvarchar(150) '$.a'
) AS j;
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax, as I mentioned, is no different:

```sql
SELECT OJ.Kom,
       OJ.[Date],
       OJ.[User]
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(YT.JSONColumn)
                 WITH ([Kom] nvarchar(max) '$.c',
                       [Date] DATETIME2  '$.d',
                       [User] nvarchar(150) '$.a') OJ;
```